# How to open a child div on hover parent?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, mouseover

I am using angular 6 and typescript to make an application and i am in the need to open the child div on click and also on hover parent.

Now as of click event regarding everything works fine but unable to do on `onmouseover` event.

**Html**

```
<ul class="list-unstyled">
    <li *ngFor="let item of items">
        {{item.order}}
        <button (onmouseover)="openCurrentOrder(item)" (click)="openCurrentOrder(item)"> Click/Hover here to open order {{item.id}} </button> <br>
        <div class="list-items inner-list-items" *ngIf="item.isActive">
            opened order {{item.id}}
        </div>
    <br><br><br>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**Ts**

```
  items: any = [
    {id: "1",order: "one", isActive: false},
    {id: "2",order: "two", isActive: false},
    {id: "3",order: "three", isActive: false},
    {id: "4",order: "four", isActive: false},
    {id: "5",order: "five", isActive: false},
  ]

  isActive: boolean = false;

  openCurrentOrder(item) {
    item.isActive = !item.isActive;
    console.log("opened");
  }
```

Kindly help me to open the child div on hover over the button as like working on click of the same.

The solution needs to be in **pure Javascript/Typescript** without jquery.

Working stackblitz 
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-t5ahud

Comment: You are probably looking for the `(mouseenter)` and `(mouseleave)` events

Comment: @Ploppy, Did you mean ```mouseenter="openCurrentOrder(item)"``` ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no `onmouseover` event in Angular, you can use built-in `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` Angular events instead:

```
<button
  (mouseenter)="openCurrentOrder(item)"
  (mouseleave)="closeCurrentOrder(item)"
  (click)="toggleCurrentOrder(item)">
  Click/Hover here to open order {{item.id}}
</button>
```

[**STACKBLITZ**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qtpasn?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Answer (score 0):

Please change the code like the below.

```
(mouseover)="openCurrentOrder(item)"
```

The working copy has updated in the below link.

Working stackblitz https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-t5ahud

Comment: Prem, Kindly don't edit on the same link that i have provided because other viewers would not able to see what i have worked in the stackblitz as like mentioned in my question. Create a new one and reflect your changes there.

Comment: Hi Mani. Sorry for editing your link. Created a new one and provide a work around for your solution in a new link. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-v9pjtt?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html